# In JavaScript, how can I refer to the button that called the function?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table. One of the cells in each row of the table contains a button. When the button is clicked, the row that contains the button should be removed from the table.

The button calls the removeItem function when it is clicked.

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeItem()" />
```

.

```
function removeItem(sender) {
    var tableTBody = document.getElementById('my_tbody');
    tableTBody.removeChild(sender.parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

In the function I used `sender` to stand for the reference to the button. The button's parent is the cell ( element) that contains it, and the cell's parent is the row that contains it.

How can I refer inside the function to the button that called the function?

Comment: _How can I refer inside the function to the button that called the function?_ By actually sending the button in your `onclick` event. You're already referencing the button then in your code as the parameter `sender`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeItem(this)" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I inserted the `this` argument and I now refer to the table's tbody instead of to the table. `my_tbody.removeChild(sender.parentNode.parentNode)` using parentNode, instead of just parent.